# is there a better way to do segmented fillna with method 'ffill' with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, fillna

Let me explain this situation. the thing is i'm currently working with data that is categorized sometimes and sometimes don't. So i decided to use fillna's pandas with 'ffil' as method. I just don't feel this is the optimal and/or cleaner solution. if someone could help me with a better aproach i'll be so grateful. Here some code to demostrate the point:

```py
data = {
    "detail":['apple mac', 'apple iphone x', 'samsumg galaxy s10', 'samsumg galaxy s10', 'hp computer'],
    'category': ['computer', 'phone', 'phone', np.NaN, np.NaN]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Returns

```py
    detail              category
0   apple mac           computer
1   apple iphone x      phone
2   samsumg galaxy s10  phone
3   samsumg galaxy s10  NaN
4   hp computer         NaN
```

first i filtered detail values without category:

```py
details_without_cats = df[df.category.isnull()].detail.unique()
```

then i loop through these values to fill if correponds:

```py
for detail_wc in details_without_cats:
    df[df.detail == detail_wc] = df[df.detail == detail_wc].fillna(method = 'ffill')
print(df)
```

returns exactly what i want

```
    detail              category
0   apple mac           computer
1   apple iphone x      phone
2   samsumg galaxy s10  phone
3   samsumg galaxy s10  phone
4   hp computer         NaN
```

the dilemma is as follows. What happens if i have this situation with thousands or millions of samples. Is there a better way? please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a dict of items with values to use later you can do this:

```
maps = df.dropna().set_index('detail').to_dict()['category']
df['category'] = df.set_index('detail').index.map(maps)
```

maps

```
{'apple mac': 'computer',
 'apple iphone x': 'phone',
 'samsumg galaxy s10': 'phone'}
```

output:

```
               detail  category
0           apple mac  computer
1      apple iphone x     phone
2  samsumg galaxy s10     phone
3  samsumg galaxy s10     phone
4         hp computer       NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do

```
df['category']=df.groupby('detail')['category'].ffill()
df
               detail  category
0           apple mac  computer
1      apple iphone x     phone
2  samsumg galaxy s10     phone
3  samsumg galaxy s10     phone
4         hp computer       NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. If we just print `df.groupby('detail')['category'].ffill()` we don't have detail as index but if we print `df.groupby('detail')['category'].count()` we do, why? Just curious about it.